# Not able to signup on https://www.google.com/dfp/

Tags: google-dfp

Unauthorised access
We apologise for the inconvenience, but you are not authorised to visit this page. If you believe this is an error, please contact your account manager.

Comment: Google recently switched from google.com/dfp to admanager.google.com. Try to log in https://admanager.google.com/

Comment: with add manager also, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Dum question, but are you sure you have a valid access ? Are you the admin ?